Finding the phase difference in Rf-SQUID
In my solution I have assumed that $\phi_{12}$ and $\phi_{ab}$ are gauge invariant. This gives me a final expression where I need to insert the flux, which I set equal to $LI$.
I'm unsure which current will contribute to the flux. Can you offer me any help?

please avoid asking questions which consist mainly of an image, and instead type out all the relevant expressions using MathJax.
